# Github - Local repository already exists. How do I create a remote github repository and sync to it?

Tags: git, github, version-control

## Summary of what I did

I frequently encounter the following problem:

- I create a folder for a project on my local machine and start working
- Later, if I want to keep this code longer term, then I would like to be able to add it to version control using Git

One solution is to:

- create a Github repo (on Github, Gitlab, Bitbucket etc)
- clone this repo from the cloud to a new directory on my local machine
- copy the files from the existing directory to the new one created by the `git clone` step above
- commit new code in the new repo and push the new changes
- finally, delete the old directory

This seems like quite a common solution, but as far as I know there is no convenient solution.

## Questions

- How do I push my work on branch master from the local repo to the remote?
- How do I pull down the new files from the remote repo to the local?
- Essentially I want to sync the 2 repos without going through the whole process of making a new folder and deleting the old one as I described above. How can I do this?

Comment: Is it a non-empty github repo that you want to push your local repo in? And do you need to keep your local repo's histories, or just add the files into github repo without keeping the local repo's commit histories?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT Yes both repos are non-empty. As for histories - I probably don't need to keep them. I probably don't need to keep all the branches either but in the case of a repo where there were more than just one branch then obviously it would be preferable to keep them.

Comment: I added an answer to keep the files together (with only keep the local history), you can have a try.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new repository on GitHub, it *tells you exactly what you need to do to use it from an existing local repository*.  This is directly from GitHub:

> …or push an existing repository from the command line
>
> ```
> git remote add origin https://github.com/YOURNAME/REPONAME.git 
> git push -u origin master
> ```

That's all.

Answer (score 1):

To can use belo way to sync local repo and remote repo (assume keep all the files in `master` branch):

```
# In your local remote
git remote add origin <github repoURL> -f
git checkout origin/master .
git commit -m 'keep remote files with local files together'
git push -u origin master -f
```

Now the github repo `master` branch contains the files both in local repo and in original github repo.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

There is no direct way to synchronize two unrelated git repositories. But there **is** a way to side-step the problem by re-naming a branch and performing a cherry-pick.

- Two repositories will be related if you have cloned one repository, thus creating another.
- Two repositories will not be related if you have created them independently.

If you create a repository on github/gitlab/bitbucket using the web user interface, this repository will be independent of any repository you create locally using `git init`. Thus, the two will have unrelated histories, and there is no "easy" way to merge them.

The most likely reason why you will find yourself in this situation is because:

- First, you created a folder on your local machine and began working.
- Later, you decided that you want this code to be under source control. You want to push it to github/gitlab/bitbucket.
- You create a repository on github/gitlab/bitbucket to push to.
- You can't clone that repository into your current working directory. You also can't initialize an empty repository in the current working directory, add code to it, and then push. (At least not easily.)

**If you find yourself in this situation, here is my suggestion of what to do:**

- Initialize an empty repository in the same working directory.
- Commit your local code to branch `master`
- Rename your local repo branch from `master` to something else. `master-local` would be a good choice.
- Do the usual `git remote add origin ...` to register the URL of the remote with a name `origin`
- You should now be able to push your local branch to origin, because it has a different name
- You should also be able to "download" `master` from origin by doing a `git fetch`, because there is no branch called `master` on the local repo.
- You will not be able to merge the two branches, becuase they have unrelated histories. However, you will be able perform a `git cherry-pick`.
- `git push`

With this approach, you keep the full history (and files) on both the remote and local `master` branches. You do not have to do any manual copying around of files. You do not lose `.gitignore` and `README` if you created them. (On the remote.)

**Note:** Ideally, you want to perform a single commit, so that there is only 1 commit hash to cherry-pick.

If you have performed multiple commits before the `cherry-pick` stage, it will be easier to squash those commits into a single commit, so that you only have to cherry-pick across a single commit hash. You can do this using an interactive rebase: `git rebase -i HEAD~n` where `n` is the number of commits to rebase.

### Detailed Instructions with List of Git Commands:

Say you have an existing working directory on your **local** machine containing some work.

**On the local machine, do:**

- `git init`
- `git checkout -b master-local`
- `git add .` (or otherwise add your files)
- `git commit`

**On the remote, do:**

- Create a remote repository on github/gitlab/bitbucket etc.
- Find the address required to `clone` the repository
- Example: `git@github.com:username/my_repo.git`

**On the local machine, do:**

- `git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:username/my_repo.git`
- `git push --set-upstream origin master-local`
- (Note: If you try `git push` git will output a message reminding you to set the upstream branch.)
- `git fetch` (Note: Should print message saying `* [new branch] master -> origin/master`)
- `git checkout master`

Note: If you now try to perform a `git merge master-local` you will get an error:

- <s>`git merge master-local`</s>

```
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Instead, perform a cherry-pick.

If you have more than one commit, first squash all your commits into a single commit so that you only have to perform a `cherry-pick` on a single commit hash. (Rather than multiple commit hashes.)

To do this, perform an interactive rebase. `git rebase -i HEAD~n` where `n` is a number of commits.

**Note:** Assuming that you are following this guide because you want to push some code to github/gitlab/bitbucket then presumably you just decided to create a local commit. This means you will probably only have one commit to cherry-pick.

- `git checkout master-local`
- `git log` (prints list of commit hashes, get the commit hash)
- `git checkout master`
- `git cherry-pick <hash>`
- `git push`

## Detailed Explanation

It has been a number of years since I added this question. There is no **direct** solution to this problem.

This is why:

- The fundamental problem is that git cannot reconcile unrelated histories
- When creating a repo, it comes with a default branch name, usually `master`
- This branch has a history (an empty one)
- The problem arises if you create two unrelated repositories with unrelated histories, one on github/gitlab/bitbucket, and one on your local machine

The usual solution to this, which is given as an example on Github, is to perform a force-push to over-write the remote (github side) branch history.

- **This does not work** if you have things on the Github side which you want to keep. (For example, did you add a `.gitignore` and a `README`?)